# C# Json: Sort alphanumeric string

Tags: c#, json, sorting

Am trying to sort fieldName by removing first char 'A', but its still not sorting properly.
Sorting alphanumeric when its required to sort only by the numbers in the string.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string _json = "{'Information': [{'FieldName': 'A104','Draft': 'Unknown'},{'FieldName': 'A02','Draft': 'Unknown'},{'FieldName': 'A101','Draft': 'Unknown'},{'FieldName': 'A03','Draft': 'Unknown'}],'OtherInfo': []}";
    var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Informat>(_json);
    var test1 = jObj.Information.OrderByDescending(x => x.FieldName.Remove(0,1));
    var sortedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1);
    jObj.Reasons = sortedJson.ToArray();

    //below too not working
    var sortedJson =
        from t in jObj.Information
        orderby t.FieldName.Remove(0,1) descending
        select t;
}
```

JSON:

```json
{
   "Information":[
      {
         "FieldName":"A104",
         "Draft":"Unknown"
      },
      {
         "FieldName":"A02",
         "Draft":"Unknown"
      },
      {
         "FieldName":"A101",
         "Draft":"Unknown"
      },
      {
         "FieldName":"A03",
         "Draft":"Unknown"
      }
   ],
   "OtherInfo":[
      
   ]
}
```

Comment: "still not sorting properly" - what does that mean? What happens currently and what do you expect should happen? Please provide an example of the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are expecting a numeric order. Even after removing the "A" the remaining string will be sorted in  lexical order. I.e., first come all the numbers starting with `0` then with `1`, etc., no matter how many digits they have.

You must convert the number to a numeric value (e.g. `int`, `long`, `decimal`) to obtain a numeric order.

```cs
var test1 = jObj.Information
    .OrderByDescending(x => Int64.Parse(x.FieldName.Remove(0,1)));
```

or

```cs
var sortedJson =
   from t in jObj.Information
   orderby Int64.Parse(t.FieldName.Remove(0,1)) descending
   select t;
```

---

If you are using C# 8.0 or above in a .NET Core project, you can also write `t.FieldName[1..]` instead of `t.FieldName.Remove(0,1)`.